# what is the difference between command and iterator pattern.?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am confused of the difference between the command pattern and iterator pattern . For me it both looks the same. Can any one please help me in this.

Comment: Could you explain where you see the similarity? Because to me they look quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are fundamentally different.

Are you sure you've even looked at an example implementation of each? And used the debugger to step through the examples to learn what they do?

- A command is an object which represents an action. It can be created by one part of the program and later be executed by any other part.
- An iterator is a means of performing the same action on all elements of a collection.